# Flutter web with Firestore: Set in every document a field to a value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set in every document of a collection, a specific field to 0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To do in dart:

Geting all documents and update fields:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("collectionName").doc("documentName").get();

snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) { 
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionName").doc(doc.id).update({
      "fieldName": 0,
    });
});
```

But I recommend using the firebase admin for this type of activity, because if there are many documents you can exceed the limits of its use in Firestore, stay tuned! With firebase admin you can use different types of languages, with python for example, and update everything at once (Batched writes), in a single activity.

Example in Python (Firebase admin):

```
reference = db.collection(u'themes')

query_snapshot = reference.where(u'collections', u'array_contains', u'reflections').stream()

batch = db.batch()

for doc in query_snapshot:
  doc_data = doc.to_dict()

  new_data = {}
  new_data["keywords_pt"] = generate_keywords(doc_data[u"title-pt"].lower())
  new_data["keywords_es"] = generate_keywords(doc_data[u"title-es"].lower())
  new_data["keywords_en"] = generate_keywords(doc_data[u"title-en"].lower())

  batch.update(reference.document(doc.id), new_data)

batch.commit()
```

For more information:

Firebase admin: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Batched writes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes